# RichTextBox does not display ' and shows up a diamond instead with a question mark inside it

Tags: .net, vb.net, text, encoding, streamreader

The picture show how the text appears below :-

[image]

Below is the code to update the RichTextBox

```
If File.Exists(C_Drive + "\compu\update.txt") Then
    Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(C_Drive + "\compu\update.txt")

    ' Read and display the lines from the file until the end 
    ' of the file is reached.
    RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text + sr.ReadToEnd
    sr.Close()
End If

RichTextBox1.Select(0, 0)
```

Comment: You will also notice that the tab character also appears as a diamond with a question mark in it . . .  I need to know what I have to do in my code so that the text appears as is from the update.txt i am uploading from. You will see from the pic I provided that the "won't" also appears wrongly !

Comment: A little something for the future: To avoid problems you should always use the ampersand (`&`) instead of the plus (`+`) when concatenating strings. `RichTextBox1.Text & sr.ReadToEnd`.

Comment: Thanks Visual Vincent - will do so :-)

Comment: Open the text file with Notepad and use Save As, use the same name and set the Encoding combobox to "UTF-8".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an issue about wrong encoding, use the `StreamReader` overload that specifies a text encoding:

- **[StreamReader Constructor (String, Encoding)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8xxf0x5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**

You need to ensure to be using the right encoding, the same as the textfile encoding has.

Example following the code that you've provided:

```
Dim textfile As New FileInfo(String.Format("{0}\compu\update.txt", C_Drive))

If textfile.Exists() Then 
    Using sr As New StreamReader(textfile.FullName, Encoding.UTF8)
        RichTextBox1.Append(sr.ReadToEnd())
    End Using
End If
```

Comment: If i just add to my code ,Encoding.UTF8 it does no difference !  !

Comment: Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(C_Drive + "\compu\update.txt", System.Text.Encoding.UTF7, False)

This helps for the tab but for won't it shows up as won t (space between n an t)

Comment: Thanks ! I just did an edit to the original text and it seems to work fine !

Comment: I'm glad to be of help!. Note that you can detect the encoding of a textfile through Notepad application (using the "**Save As**" option), and through the .Net encoding classes.

Comment: An afterthought . . . If I use encoding.ASCII it seems to work the best for .txt files

Comment: I cannot believe someone actually seems to have downvoted this.

Comment: Yes, someone downvoted, maybe a hater, a kid, or just a Troll, who knows... that's the main problem of **StackExchange**'s sites, that let's everybody be able to judge any question or answer, without any kind of reasoning.